# Is it possible to disable cache on certain fields?

Tags: 8, caching

I am working on a site where i'm implementing my own cookie bar module.
For this module i have made it possible to write something in the CKeditor like:

[image]

Where everything between the {cookie} tags is only visible when cookies are accepted. This works fine on my dev environment, but when I deployed it to the test server where cache is enabled it won't show any change when you enable/disable cookies because the page is already cached.

Is there a way to disable cache on the text field or better yet, everything between the cookie tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the cache context of the node.

If the cookie is a drupal session, use the predefined cache context for this:

```
$build['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'session.exists';
```

If you target another cookie, that drupal is not aware of, you would need to create your own context, more info:

https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/cache/contexts